# Bazel - best documentation for which providers are used by any given rule?

Tags: bazel

I am writing a custom rule that takes inputs from `cc_library`, `cc_binary`, `apple_static_library`, and a few other platform-specific rules. I'd like to view each API given to me via referencing `ctx.attr.foo` inside the custom rule's implementation function.

There is a list of providers here https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/skylark-provider.html but it doesn't say which rules are using them.

Is there a best practice for viewing what these rules are providing me, or does it require going through the source for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of providers for a given target with [dir](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#dir). Something like this is helpful for debugging:

```py
def _print_attrs_impl(ctx):
  for target in ctx.attr.targets:
    print('%s: %s' % (target.label, dir(target)))
```

Printing from inside a rule you're developing is often helpful too, to verify targets are actually what you expect them to be.

You can also apply `dir` to the providers themselves, to see what fields they have.

Comment: From my experiments “dir” lists object properties, but not providers. For instance, for cc_library label dir gives me "actions", "data_runfiles", "default_runfiles", "files", "files_to_run", "label", "output_groups". But it does not allow me to see that I can query it for OutputGroupInfo or CcInfo providers using square brackets syntax. If I know which providers to expect I can test for its presence: if CcInfo in obj: cc_info = obj[CcInfo]   but if I don’t knowwhat to expect (or want to list all providers available in the object) I don’t see a way to achieve it without using aspects.

Comment: Here's example code on how to check for presence of a provider: https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/master/rules/optional_provider/sum.bzl#L14

Answer (score 2):

This is how you get all providers and output groups from a target:

```
bazel cquery my_target --output=starlark --starlark:expr="providers(target)"
```